# Reading binary files in Cython

Tags: cython, binaryfiles

I am attempting to read a binary file in Cython. Previously this was working in Python, but I am looking to speed up the process. This code below was written as a familiarisation and logic check before writing the complete module. Once this section is complete the code will be expanded to read in multiple 400 Mb files and process.

A function was created that opens the file, reads in a number of data point and returns them to an array.

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free 
from libc.stdio cimport fopen, fclose, FILE, fscanf, fread

def readin_binary(filename, int number_of_points):
    """
    Test reading in a file and returning data
    """
    header_bytes = <unsigned char*>malloc(number_of_points)
    filename_byte_string = filename.encode("UTF-8")
    cdef FILE *in_binary_file
    in_binary_file = fopen(filename_byte_string, 'rb')
    if in_binary_file is NULL:
        print("file not found")
    else:                       
        print("Read file {}".format(filename))
        fread(&header_bytes, 1, number_of_points, in_binary_file)
    fclose(in_binary_file)
    return header_bytes    

print(hDVS.readin_binary(filename, 10))
```

The code compiles.

When the code is run the following error occurs:

[Python has stopped working error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za9wd.png)

I've been playing with this for a few days now. I think there is a simple error but I can not see it. Any ideas?

Comment: That is a crash.

Comment: Have you determined yet if you're not already reading data as fast as the hard drive can provide it?

Comment: Did you inspect the generated C Code? Does it happen for any file? If yes could you provide a minimal file and Python code needed to reproduce the shown error?

Comment: Hi @MSeifert 
I have checked a few files and the result is the same. 
I had a look at the *.c file. I do not know where to start with this file - very complex. 
The attached zip file contains the test python module. In the \test\ directory is test.py which calls the Cython function readin_binary().

Comment: You should make your example complete, that means also all necessary imports, so it can be used with copy and paste.

Comment: Assuming it is fread from c ( how to know without cimports?), it should be fread(header_bytes,....), without &.

Comment: The following link is the code used. 
[link](https://github.com/PowerPlum/cython_binary)

Comment: did you follow ead's comment and remove the &? [fread](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm) takes a pointer as first argument

Comment: @ead, Silmathoron, MSeifert, Robert Harvey
Thank you for your input. The & symbol in the fread() statement was the cause of the crash.